# I can't install Ubuntu in my Dell laptop using a bootable pendrive

Tags: system-installation

Can anyone help me with this error?  I get this error after plugging in my Ubuntu pendrive:

```
error: symbol 'grub_register_command_lockdown' not found.
error: symbol 'grub_register_command_lockdown' not found.

Press any key to continue...
```

[image]

Comment: How did you make your Ubuntu pendrive? What tool did you use? Do you want to install Ubuntu to the pendrive or to the hard drive? there may be many reasons that a bootable USB is not booting, see: https://askubuntu.com/a/1190765/43926

Comment: @David how do you expect the OP to post text, is he suppose to retype it? In this case how is retyping the screen shot and posting it as text help answer the question?

Comment: @C.S.Cameron : Pictures of text cannot be found by searching.  Consequently, unless the text is typed, no future visitor facing the same message can find this Question by searching.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [error: symbol 'grub\_register\_command\_lockdown' not found when installing Ubuntu 21.04 in BIOS mode](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1333512/error-symbol-grub-register-command-lockdown-not-found-when-installing-ubuntu)

Comment: @Eric Towers That was not needed to answer this question. or many others. In many cases it may help get an answer, but it is not a requirement of Ask Ubuntu.

Comment: @C.S.Cameron : Apparently it *is* [resolved](https://meta.askubuntu.com/questions/8713/why-do-people-post-screenshots-of-their-terminals) at AskUbuntu that screenshots of text are inappropriate.  Further, if OP had searched for the text of his message, he would have found the Answer without creating this duplicate Question.

Comment: @Eric Towers Why do you say it is resolved? There are some good reasons listed on that page for posting photos. I do not see it as a rule in Ask Ubuntu Help. Some photos of boot screens cover a whole page of writing. These would not be practical for the OP to transcribe, nor necessarily helpful.

Answer (score 8):

If you used Rufus to create the installation USB stick, then you’ll need to [download version 3.14](https://github.com/pbatard/rufus/releases) (or newer) and recreate the media. Otherwise, [there is a security patch](https://lists.gnu.org/archive/html/grub-devel/2021-03/msg00012.html) that will need to be installed.

[This comes from the developer of Rufus](https://askubuntu.com/a/1333513/1222991) who recently provided a bit of detail about why the issue is happening

Comment: Hey, welcome back.

Comment: but 3.13 works perfectly for me... (I use it all the time)