# Live system won't boot: error: symbol 'grub_register_command_lockdown' not found

Tags: system-installation, live-usb

I am trying to load Ubuntu using a USB Flash Drive (32GB) on a Compaq Presario X1000 Laptop that is running Windows 7 (unfortunately haven’t had luck updating it) and every time I try to boot it I get this error message:

```
error: symbol 'grub_register_command_lockdown' not found
```

Is there a particular version of Ubuntu I should use to avoid this?

Any help would be more than appreciated.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [error: symbol 'grub\_register\_command\_lockdown' not found when installing Ubuntu 21.04 in BIOS mode](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1333512/error-symbol-grub-register-command-lockdown-not-found-when-installing-ubuntu)

Comment: Yes I think so. Thank you! I was running it through Rufus 3.13. Going to try Rufus 3.14 and see if it fixes.

Comment: ok, try it and report back :)

Comment: Must need to try the Ubuntu 20.04(LTS) as mentioned in other comment because the 21.10 didn’t work this go around. Does ISO or DD matter when putting on Flash Drive with Rufus?

Comment: yeah, it matters, you may want to verify the ISO first before installing.

Comment: Also, avoid using Rufus, try using [Etcher](https://www.balena.io/etcher/), it is more friendly then Rufus and will verify the iso for you too.

Comment: Okay I will try that thank you

Comment: Another option would be to use https://www.ventoy.net/

Comment: I’ll try that. Couldn’t get etcher to work either. It’s a Compaq Presario X1000 with 1.25GB RAM, Windows 7 Home Premium, Intel Pentium M Processor 1400MHz 1.40 GHz, 32-bit. Gets stuck at Ubuntu screen with circle and stick figure person at bottom center of screen.

Comment: Keeps giving me a “Please use a kernel appropriate for your CPU” message something about pae

Answer (score 0):

Try Ubuntu 20.04. The suffix LTS means Long Term Support.

It's stable and I've been using it myself.

Comment: Alright. I just put Ubuntu 21.10 amd64.iso on a 32GB flash drive using Rufus 13.14.1788 about to see if it works if not will try that.